# Как вызвать перендер определенного компонента

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend

Здравстуйте,столкнулся с такой проблемой. Есть форма для ввода. После отправки формы нужно перерендерить компонент туду листа с новой задачей без перезагрузки страницы. Какими методами этого можно достичь. Сам компонент листа через юз еффект делает запрос к бд и получает массив данных и кидает их в useState переменную но если отправить форму без перезагрузки страницы то лист останеться со старыми данными до момента перезагрузки страницы.Нужен еффект подобный хуку useEffect но без использования [],т.к. сам вызывет проблемы с производительностью

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно сделать ваш `useEffect(....,[version])`, где `version` -- стейт.
Форму посылать через `fetch`/`POST` и в `then` делать`setVersion(v=>v+1)`

Comment: Благодарю,все запилил,теперь в приложении отсутствуют моменты перезагрузки страницы полностью!)

Comment: Всегда рад. Вопрос можно принимать галочкой.