# Как обновить компонент при изменении данные в AsyncStorage в React Native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Всем привет! Создаю корзину для магазина и сталкивался с такой проблемой: При нажатий кнопки **addToCart** компонент **CartIcon**  автоматический не обновляется (( Что сделать ???  *(Задача такая чтобы было через AsyncStorage, а не redux)*

**Main.js**

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'
import { View, Text } from 'react-native'

import Product from './Product'
import CartIcon from './CartIcon'

class Main extends Component{
    render(){
        return(
           <View>
              <Text>Main Page</Text>
              <Product title="Iphone" price="100000" count="1" />
              <Product title="Samsung" price="100000" count="1" />
              <Product title="Redmi" price="100000" count="1" />

              <CartIcon />

           </View> 
        )
    }
}

export default Main
```

**Product.js**

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'
import { View, Text, AsyncStorage, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native'

class Product extends Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props)

        this.state = {
            cart: null
        }
    }

    addToCart(){
        const { price, count } = this.props

        const itemcart = {
            quantity:  count,
            price: price
        }

        AsyncStorage.getItem('cart').then((datacart)=>{
            if (datacart !== null) {
                // We have data!!
                const cart = JSON.parse(datacart)
                cart.push(itemcart)
                AsyncStorage.setItem('cart',JSON.stringify(cart));
            } else{
                const cart  = []
                cart.push(itemcart)
                AsyncStorage.setItem('cart',JSON.stringify(cart));
            }
            alert("Added to Cart")
        })
        .catch((err)=>{
            alert(err)
        })
    }

    render(){
        return(
           <View>
              <Text>{this.props.title}</Text>
              <Text>{this.props.price}</Text>
              <Text>{this.props.count}</Text>
              <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.addToCart()}></TouchableOpacity>
           </View> 
        )
    }
}

export default Product
```

**CartIcon.js**

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'
import { View, Text, AsyncStorage } from 'react-native'

class CartIcon extends Component{

    constructor(props){
        super(props)

        this.state = {
            cart: null
        }
    }

    componentDidMount(){

        AsyncStorage.getItem('cart').then((cart)=>{
            if (cart !== null) {
              // We have data!!
              const cartfood = JSON.parse(cart)
              this.setState({cart: cartfood})
            }
        })
        .catch((err)=>{
            alert(err)
        })
    }

    render(){
       const { cart } = this.state

       let price = 0

       if(cart !== null){
            this.state.cart.map((item,i)=>{
                price += item.price * item.quantity
            })
        }

       return(
          <View>
            <Text> Total Sum: {price} </Text>
          </View>
        )
    }
}

export default CartIcon
```

Comment: если делать на хуках, то принцип такой:
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1175081/Как-вызвать-перендер-определенного-компонента/1175110#1175110

Answer (score 1):

Можно сделать стейт с версией в общем парент компоненте.

Пробросить функцию инкремента версии в компонент Product.

Пробросить значение версии в CartIcon.

Позавершению setItem делать инкремент версии.

В CartIcon делать getItem по изменению (prop) версии.